# How to use items param in TemplatePicker to draw with?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, template

I have been checking the JS API of TemplatePicker and it says to either use featureLayers or items in the params object:

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/templatepicker-amd.html

I would like to use items in the templatePicker, all the examples I've seen use the featureLayers param. I have attempted to implement the following code:

```
var symbol =  new esri.symbol.SimpleMarkerSymbol(esri.symbol.SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_SQUARE, 10,

   new esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol(esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,

   new esri.Color([255,0,0]), 1),

   new esri.Color([0,255,0,0.25]));

var items = [
  { label: "item 1", symbol: symbol, description: "description 1" },
  { label: "item 2", symbol: symbol, description: "description 2" },
  { label: "item 3", symbol: symbol, description: "description 3" },
  { label: "item 4", symbol: symbol, description: "description 4" }
];

 var templatePicker = new TemplatePicker({
            items : items,
            grouping: true,
            rows: "auto",
            columns: 3
          }, "templateDiv");
```

The following error is displayed when clicking any of the items:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'geometryType' of undefined

Obviously I'm missing something, but I can't find any more detailed documentation about this.

**Update:**

I've looked into it some more and found that the function _activateDrawToolbar in Editor.js is called upon. Which in turn calls _toDrawTool and passes along templatePicker's featureLayer which causes the error because featureLayer is undefined. This seems to be the wrong behaviour seeing as I indicated templatePicker should use items and not featurelayers. In the documentation it clearly states:

> FeatureLayers or items are required all other parameters are optional.
>   See options list.